# flash spacing on line break in text field

Tags: css, flash, actionscript-3, text

I've got a dynamic html text field in flash which pulls content from an XML file, which is being generated by a CMS using CK Editor. I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it, but flash represents a `<br/>` tag with a space that seems more fitting for a `<p>` tag, and a `<p>` tag renders with about double that amount. How do I control this? I've tried specifying margins in the flash css file, but it has no effect. Is there something I can declare in the actual actionscript code?

Comment: Sorry, but i didn't really get what your problem is. What is it you want to do exactly? What is it you want to declare in the AS code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that TextFormat.leading isn't the problem or the solution.

Out of curiosity, is the `<br />` tag followed by an actual return in the xml?

Try using:

```
XML.ignoreWhitespace = true;
```

and/or

```
TextField.condenseWhite = true;
```

to your actual xml and textfield.

Comment: TextField.condenseWhite fixed the problem. Thanks Trevor!

Answer (score 0):

How about adjusting the *leading* property using a CSS [Stylesheet](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/StyleSheet.html) or a [TextFormat](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextFormat.html)?

Or adjust the Property panel settings for the TextField if it's on Stage.
[image]

Comment: I'm creating the field dynamically. Leading affects the spacing between lines, but not between paragraphs per se. It's the spacing between paragraph tags thats causing the problems. I'm already adjusting the leading. But thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

With XML files that have line breaks, Flash usually interprets those as TWO line breaks. One for the CR character (carriage return) and one for the LF characte (line feed): \r and \n, respectively. I always filter the CR's out by using this:

```
text = text.split('\r').join('');
```

This may be why you see those empty lines.

Comment: wait, so do I apply this to the textfield itself, or textfield.text?

Comment: to the text (String) that has to go in the TextField. Preferably before setting it to textField.text